# Programa em C para gerar termos de uma P.G

Tags: c

Sou iniciante à linguagem C, e encontrei um problema no código abaixo.

A questão é a seguinte: O programa roda perfeitamente, porém, ao inserir valores como (1-5-3), o programa, que deveria retornar (1-5-25), retorna (1-5-24).

Revisei o meu código várias vezes, e o refiz, porém, o erro prospera.

P.S.: Após vários testes, percebi que o erro acontece quando **'rate' tem um valor que termina em 5**, por exemplo: 5, 15, 155.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()

{
    int init, rate, n_terms, termo_pg,
        count;

    printf("Elemento inicial da P.G.: \n");
    scanf("%d", &init);

    printf("Razao da P.G.: \n");
    scanf("%d", &rate);

    printf("Numero de termos da P.G.: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n_terms);

    for (count = 1; count <= n_terms; count++)
    {
        termo_pg = init*pow(rate, count-1);
        printf("Elemento %d da P.G.: %d \n", count, termo_pg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Peço desculpas pela simples pergunta, como disse, sou iniciante, atualmente estudo pelo site cprogressivo.net, e pretendo me aprofundar na linguagem C.

Comment: A saída deu certo pra mim.

Comment: A saída tambem esta correta para mim. Não vejo problemas no codigo.

Comment: Como já disseram, não parece haver nada de errado aqui. A única coisa que eu recomendaria são umas frescurinhas: você pode declarar a variável termo_pg dentro do loop ao invés de no topo da função e você podia ter feito o for começando do zero: `for(count = 0; count < n; count++)`. Além de poupar o "-1" na conta, iterar começando do zero é o "padrão" em C (isso ficará claro quando vc começar a ver vetores)

Comment: É fácil testar (e perceber que, como os colegas já disseram, não parece estar errado) aqui: https://ideone.com/wAMwGI

Comment: que SO e compilador estas a usar?

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas respostas! Testei o código em outro computador, e também deu certo. Talvez, o erro esteja no meu antigo notebook mesmo, vai entender.

Comment: Hugomg, grato pelas dicas, seguirei as recomendações.

pmg, estou utilizando o Windows 7 atualmente, e o compilador Code::Blocks

Answer (score 1):

Talvez o teu `pow()` seja esquisito e `pow(5, 3) == 124.9999999999213453562`.

Sugestao:

```
termo_pg = init * pow(rate, count-1) + 0.000001; // arredonda para cima
```

ou escreve uma funcao similar a `pow` que trabalhe apenas com inteiros, sem introduzir virgula flutuante no problema (podes deixar de usar `<math.h>`).

Answer (score 1):

Como a função pow trabalha com números de ponto flutuante, realmente pode estar ocorrendo um problema de arredondamento ou truncagem.

É bem simples fazer uma função de exponenciação com inteiros:

```
long potencia(long base, long expoente)
{
    long i;
    long r = 1;

    for( i = 0 ; i < expoente ; i++ )
        r = r * base;

    return r;
}
```